# help replicating fuzzy equations from a paper

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I'm trying to replicate [Zhou](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-73289-1_65)'s Paper on quantifying UX using Fuzzy Math.

In their model, there is a weight vector $A$ for a set of characteristics. in the paper's test case the characteristics were **Effectiveness, Efficiency**, and **Satisfaction** with weights `[0.4434, 0.1692, 0.3874]`, respectively. The method of obtaining these weights was something i was able to replicate.

along with this, a rating matrix $R$ which in the each category has 5 bins of discrete ratings:
`[Excellent, Good, Medium, Poor, Very Poor]`. So for the category **effectiveness**, `68.75%` of the respondents had an `Excellent` rating while the remainder had a rating of `Good`. Giving us `[0.6875, 0.3125, 0, 0, 0]` the scores for **Efficiency** and **Satisfaction** were similarly obtained which gives us:

|  | Excellent | Good | Medium | Poor | Very Poor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Effectiveness | 0.6875 | 0.3125 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Efficiency | 0.25 | 0.3125 | 0.0625 | 0.25 | 0.125 |
| Satisfaction | 0.125 | 0.625 | 0.25 | 0 | 0 |

The next step describes getting the appraisal vector $B$ where $B = A ∘ R$ where they describe the $∘$ as the composition operator $M(⋅,⊕)$. I'll directly take a chunk of the paper to show how they described the operator: [Zhou (2015), Eq(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqBhK.png)

This is where I fail to replicate the math. It seems to equate $B$ onto two different values. it says $B$ is equal to $A ⋅ R$ but the the same time is also equal to $min(1, A ⋅ R)$. Specifically,

$b_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i r_{ij} = min \{1,\sum_{i=1}^n a_i r_{ij}\}$

where the weight vector is

$A = (a_1, a_2, ...)$

and the rating vector is
$R = 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    r_{11} & r_{12} & \cdots & r_{1m}\\
    r_{21} & r_{22} & \cdots & r_{2m}\\
    r_{31} & r_{32} & \cdots & r_{3m}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
    r_{n1} & r_{n2} & \cdots & r_{nm} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
$

In the example,

$B = A ∘ R = [0.3956, 0.3711, 0.1758, 0.0156, 0.0313]$

I should note that $b_1$ or the first element of $B$ which has a value of `0.3956` has the same value when i do a simple dot product, but the rest of the values ($b_2$ to $b_5$) have glaringly different values. i also can't seem to place where I'd actually do the $\alpha ⊕ \beta =  min(1, \alpha + \beta)$ operation as described in the paper.

can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you. edited.